# Cant add date in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to add the date in rails form. For example

```
def create
@land=current_user.lands.build(land_params)

if @land.save
  session[:land_id]=@land.id
  flash[:success]="Success"
  redirect_to lands_path
else
  flash[:error]="Fail!!"
  render 'new'
end
  end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "lands", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "DateStart"
  t.date "DateEnd"
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @land do |f| %>
    <p>Information</p>
  <%= f.label :Start %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateStart, :default => @DateStart, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>

  <%= f.label :End %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateEnd,:default => @DateEnd,:order => [:month, :day, :year]%>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p>Start : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
<p>End : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
```

Land.controller

```
def show
    @land= Land.find(params[:id])
end
```

But nothing is printed out in my show.html.erb. When I check database my DateStart and DateEnd is nil. I don't know what wrong. Can you give me some advice? Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your `create` action where do you create the Land entities?

Comment: Are you sure to create your data after form submit?

Comment: @nemesv i edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow like below

```
def create
    @land= Land.new(land_params)
    @land.user = current_user
    if @land.save
       flash[:success] = 'Land was successfully created.'
       redirect_to lands_path #=> or anything
    else
       flash[:error] = 'Land was not created successfully .'
       redirect_to lands_path #=> or anything
    end
end
```

I think that's work

You make sure add this `before_action :authenticate_user!` on your controller header, that's cannot access user without authentication

Hope to help

Comment: Cool, although it's not the answer , when i look at your post ,i find out that in my land_params , i haven't permitted DateStart and DateEnd yet. So i  think your post make me solve my problem.  Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You can follow my answers -

Method - 1. No association with User and Land model.

lands_controller.rb file look like -

```
class LandsController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @DateStart = Date.today 
   @DateEnd = Date.today + 2.days
   @land = Land.new 
  end

  def create
   @land = Land.new(land_params)    
   if @land.save
    session[:land_id] = @land.id
    flash[:success]= "Success"
    redirect_to lands_path
   else
    flash[:error] = "Fail!!"
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @land= Land.find(params[:id])
 end

 def land_params
   params.require(:land).permit(:DateStart, :DateEnd)
 end
end
```

Database Schema file look like - (schema.rb)

```
create_table "lands", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "DateStart"
  t.date "DateEnd"
end
```

Lands controller new action view file - (app/views/lands/new.html.erb)

```
 <%= form_for @land do |f| %>
  <p>Information</p>
  <%= f.label :Start %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateStart, :default => @DateStart, :order => [:month,   :day, :year] %>

  <%= f.label :End %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateEnd,:default => @DateEnd,:order => [:month, :day, :year]%>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Lands view page (app/views/lands/show.html.erb)

```
<p>Start : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
<p>End : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
```

Method - 2. Association with User and Land model.

lands_controller.rb file look like - (app/controllers/lands_controller.rb)

```
class LandsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!

 def new    
   @DateStart = Date.today 
   @DateEnd = Date.today + 2.days
   @land = current_user.lands.build 
 end

 def create
  @land = current_user.lands.build(land_params)    
  if @land.save
    session[:land_id] = @land.id
    flash[:success]= "Success"
    redirect_to lands_path
  else
   flash[:error] = "Fail!!"
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
  @land= Land.find(params[:id])
 end

 def land_params
   params.require(:land).permit(:DateStart, :DateEnd)
 end
end
```

Database Schema file look like - (schema.rb)

```
create_table "lands", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.date "DateStart"
 t.date "DateEnd"
 t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_rooms_on_user_id"
end
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 t.string   "reset_password_token"
 t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
 t.datetime "remember_created_at"
 t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
 t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
 t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
 t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
 t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
 t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false    
 t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
 t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

User model look like - (app/models/user.rb)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lands
end
```

Land model look like - (app/models/land.rb)

```
class Land < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Lands controller new action view file - (app/views/lands/new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for @land do |f| %>
  <p>Information</p>
  <%= f.label :Start %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateStart, :default => @DateStart, :order => [:month, :day, :year] %>

  <%= f.label :End %><br />
  <%= f.date_select :DateEnd,:default => @DateEnd,:order => [:month, :day, :year]%>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

Lands view page (app/views/lands/show.html.erb)

```
<p>Start : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
<p>End : <%= @land.DateEnd %></p>
```

I hope it should work.